# Updating IOS's via SCP in bash with expect

Tags: ios, bash, expect, cisco

Good day. I am attempting to create/run a script that will allow me to send an updated IOS from a server to my network devices. The following code works when I put in a manual IP address right before the ":flash" command.

```
 #!/user/bin/expect
 set IOSroot "/xxxxx/xxx/c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE10a.bin"
 set pw xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

 spawn scp $IOSroot 1.1.1.1:flash:/c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE10a.bin

 expect "TACACS Password:"
 send "$pw\r"
 interact
```

The code there works great and as expected. The issue arises when I try to use a file called "ioshost" with a list of IP's and use that within this script to get some automation. I have tried various things to get this to work. Some of them are as follows:

Settings Variables

```
IPHosts=$(cat ioshost)

set IPHost 'cat ioshost'
```

Along with trying to use the read/do command...

```
while read line; do
spawn scp $IOSroot $line:flash:/c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE10a.bin
done < ioshost
```

None of these seem to work and I am looking for guidance. Please note I understand that setting a password is not best practice but setting RSA keys as mentioned in other articles is not allowed so I am forced to do it this way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried "echoing" your scp command inside the loop, jut to see if what you get is what you expect?  I would quote the "$IOSroot" expansion, as well as the "$line".  I would also use "while IFS= read -r line".  But these may not be the problem, depending on the actual data contained.

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with the syntax you are using for scp (IP:flash:/...).  I am used to seing user@host:/path.  Could you please help me figure it out?

Comment: Fred, the SCP portion that I am running is the syntax identifies where the IOS is loaded on our JUMP server and then the second portion is the target device and the path that I want it sent to.

Comment: An `expect` script is not a `bash` script; you cannot use shell constructs like `while`.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the information. I was wondering if that was possibly the case as I saw in many other questions, folks were trying to combine both into one item.

Comment: @Fred I am unsure where I should put the echo portion into my script. I tried "echo ioshost" and it just repeats the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one Expect script and one Bash script.

First update your Expect script a bit:

```
#!/user/bin/expect
set IOSroot "/xxxxx/xxx/c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE10a.bin"
set pw xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

spawn scp $IOSroot [lindex $argv 0]:flash:/c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE10a.bin
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

expect "TACACS Password:"
send "$pw\r"
interact
```

Then write a simple Bash `for` loop:

```
for host in $(<ioshost); do
    expect /your/script.exp $host
done
```

Comment: This worked great! I ask how the lindex portion works! Thanks again!