# expect script to access jump server then ssh to routers in the network. Loop is not working

Tags: expect

I am wondering if you coudl advise. I am writing a script to ssh to a jump server, the access all routers on the network using a loop and read from a file.
"expect name-of-script.exp routerlist"

I am able to access the jump server, then the loop is not working. so from the jump server, no ssh to the router is taking place. Could you please advise?

## Regards;

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

# This script is used to connect to lab router
# Usage: connect <router>
#

set timeout -1

set devicelist [lindex $argv 0]
#set command_list [lindex $argv 1]
set username  [lindex $argv 1]
#set password [lindex $argv 2]
set list [open $devicelist r]
spawn ssh myusername@x.x.x.x
expect "Password:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "$"
#log_user 0

while {[gets $list line] != -1} {
        send_user "\n----------$line----------\n"
        send --  "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$line\r"

        expect "(yes/no)?"
        send -- "yes\r"
        expect  "*assword:"
        send "router-password\r"

        expect ">"

        send_user "########################## $route###########\n"
        send "show chassis hardware detail | display xml | no-more\n";
        expect "> "
        send -- "exit\r"
        expect "*$"
        }
send "quit\n";
exit 0;
```

Comment: Could you write a simpler *Expect* script and write a *for* loop in *shell*? See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755511/ .

Comment: Thank you very much :-). However, if I have to do that, I would have to ssh to the second jump server for each router. I may have more than 100 routers. So, that is why I prefer to jump from my local server to the jump server, then loop the routers names and excute the commands. But I will try that just to see if I can run commands from my local server.